# R use both sumCol and aggregate

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

Is there a nice way to sum and aggregate the following dataframe:

```
Persons     item1, item2, item3, ....
1           0      1      3      ....
1           2      2      4      ....
2           1      2      4      ....
3           0      1      1      ....
1           1      1      1      ....
...         ...    ...    ...    ....
```

To:

```
Persons  Items
1        15
2        7
3        2
...      ...
```

So basically sum up all the items for each person and add that sum to another row (if that person has another row).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
library(dplyr)

Persons <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1)
item1 <- c(0, 2, 1, 0, 1)
item2 <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
item3 <- c(3, 4, 4, 1, 1)

data_1 <- data.frame(Persons, item1, item2, item3)

data_1$Items_raw <- rowSums(data_1[,2:4])
data_1 <- data_1 %>% group_by(Persons) %>% summarize(Items = sum(Items_raw))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could use `tapply`...

```
tapply(rowSums(df[,-1]), df[,1], sum)

 1  2  3 
15  7  2
```

Comment: This does return a table with the persons and the sum but it removes the persons with multiple entries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Persons = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1),
  item1 = c(0, 2, 1, 0, 1),
  item2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1),
  item3 = c(3, 4, 4, 1, 1)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(Persons) %>% 
  summarise(items = sum(item1, item2, item3))
```

And you'll obtain:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Persons items
    <dbl> <dbl>
1       1    15
2       2     7
3       3     2
```

Comment: The ellipsis (dots) means there is more than the 3 mentioned. Probably you need, `sum(across(everything()))`

Comment: Thanks for you comment guys, but i can't seem to get it to work. It keeps returning an empty 1x1 tibble. I changed the df into data (the name) and the items to sum(across(everything))

Comment: This may work: 
`df %>% group_by(Persons) %>% summarise(items= sum(across(where(is.numeric))))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to combining all the reaction under my post (thanks everyone!), I found a solution to my problem. I solved it the following way:

```
People = data.frame(People$Persons, 
rowSums(People[, 2:522]))
colnames(People) = c("Persons", "Items")
People = ddply(People, "Persons", numcolwise(sum))
```

Its not a beautiful solution (wish I could do it in 1 line) but it works!